# SOQL - Check if record exists without throwing null error

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to check and see if a user has a record in another object. I am pretty sure that the way I have it coded right now will throw a null pointer exception if no record is found. How do I do the check while avoiding the error?

```
public class EmpMerge_Controller {

public  boolean                 isAdmin     {get; set;}

public EmpMerge_Controller() {
    showRecords         = TRUE;

    //Check if user has Admin checkbox in hub
    isAdmin             = FALSE;
    BCS__c adminCheck   = [Select ID 
                           FROM BCS__c
                           WHERE Admin__c = TRUE
                           AND User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    if(adminCheck != null){
        isAdmin = TRUE;
    }
```

....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a List collection and check if it is empty

```
public  boolean                 isAdmin     {get; set;}

public EmpMerge_Controller() {
    showRecords         = TRUE;

    //Check if user has Admin checkbox in hub
    BCS__c[] adminCheck   = [Select ID 
                           FROM BCS__c
                           WHERE Admin__c = TRUE
                           AND User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    isAdmin = !adminCheck.isEmpty();
```

Comment: `isAdmin = !adminCheck.isEmpty();` avoids having to set the variable up to 2 times as well as an if statement.

Comment: @sfdcfox - good points. I did not put the effort I should have into cleaning up the OP original code. I have made that change.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using COUNT() for this purpose:

```
isAdmin = [SELECT COUNT() 
           FROM BCS__c 
           WHERE Admin__c = TRUE AND 
           User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()] > 0;
```

The `> 0` at the end takes the count of records, which is a number, and compares it to 0; if we have a non-zero result, then there was at least one record.

Comment: The only problem then is you will need to use another SOQL query to interpret the records should the result be greater than 0. With the solution that @Eric proposed you can If(List of Results <0) then do this to the records. - If the OP does not need to do anything with the returned results then your solution is valid and smaller in terms of code footprint.

Comment: @developer__c Yeah, just providing a "shortcut" that is pretty cool, since it saves a temporary variable if you don't need it. The right tool for the right time.

Comment: Might as well add `LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using size()

```
public boolean isAdmin     {get; set;}
........

Integer exists = [SELECT Id 
               FROM BCS__c 
               WHERE Admin__c = TRUE AND 
               User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId()].size();
isAdmin =  exists > 0;
```